# How i can get what key was pressed in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

How to display what key was pressed?

I mean, like if you press A, on screen will display: You pressed A.

```
cin>>keypress;
cout<<"You pressed:"<<keypress;
```

I want to show directly what key I am pressing. Without waiting to press enter and finishing the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to display the character what are you pressing (like in your example). So, it's pretty simple. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
    char keyPress;
    while(1)
        {
            keyPress=_getch();
            if((keyPress==27)||(keyPress==32))
            {
                printf("You decided to stop the execution of this code.");
                return 0;
            }
            printf("You pressed:%c\n",keyPress);
        }
}
```

If you let the code how it is, the program will finish the execution on esc or space pressed. If you want to change this, you can replace the numbers in: `if((keyPress==27)||(keyPress==32))` with anothers ascii codes of your button. Here's all the ascii codes: https://ascii.cl/ . If you want to end the program only on one button, just modify from `if((keyPress==27)||(keyPress==32))` into `if(keyPress==27)` and now the program will stop only on ESC.

Comment: I can display `You pressed: Space` for space?

Comment: Recommend replacing 27 and 32 with meaningful identifiers. ASCII, while the most common encoding by far, is not the only encoding. It is worth adding a few lines to the answer explaining why `cin >> keypress` does not work. Note to those who follow: conio.h is a Windows header. To do this on another operating system you will need [a curses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)).

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper yeah. You can do it. Just delete space button(32 ascii) from if statement and put a new if condtition like this: `if(keyPress==32){ printf("You pressed: Space."); }`

@user4581301 What you mean? Replacing ASCII with another "encoding"? And he said that he don't want to press enter every user input. std::cin wait for enter to pe pressed.

Comment: The encoding is the mapping of numbers to characters. The most common encoding is ASCII, but not all computers use ASCII. Space is character 64 on some computers I've run across and there are probably others that I haven't run across. But the really important part is which is easier to infer the programmers intent from: `32` or `' '`. I'll grant you the esc character, it's not guaranteed to be represented as `'\e', so you can't be 100% certain what code is in use.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Windows only solution using the windows api.
`#include <wInDoWs.h>`.

you can use `GetAsyncKeyState()` and pass the ASCII value for the key to it. It will return a short indicating the status of the button. To the best of my knowledge, the value -32767 is returned when the button is pressed. Wrap that in a function and you can tell if the button is pressed. (below will run with copy/paste.)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

bool pressed(const short& _key)
{
 short state = 0;
 short pressed= -32767;
 state = GetAsyncKeyState( _key);

 return ( state == pressed );
}

int main()
{
 //see if J is pressed
 while(1)
 {
   if(pressed( 0x4a ) )// 'J'
    std::cout << "J";
 }
}
```

To make that work with all characters, I'm afraid I can't think of an easier way than storing all the ASCII values, and what you want to print out if the key is pressed, in a container and checking their pressed status every frame.(below is just pseudo code.)

```
//the container         this short is the 'key'
std::vector< std::pair< short , std::string > > chars;

//to check the status
for(auto& c : chars)
   if( pressed( c.first ) ) std::cout << c.second;
```

I would put that in some sort of loop.

Adding the 'you pressed space' wouldn't be difficult this way.
just do

`chars.push_back( std::pair<int,std::string>(0x20 , "Spacebar") );`